# Xamarin Forms listitem (on)hold gesture

Tags: xamarin.forms, c#-3.0

I have a listview with labels and entries. I want a gesture or somthing that when I long press a label it wil show an alert display with the name of the label. So far I have only when you press once, need the same but then when you press longer.

My code of the listview

```
var listView = new ListView();
        var productDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
        {

            var grid = new Grid();
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
            {
                Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star)
            });
            var typeLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White};
            typeLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Type");
            var entry = new Entry
            { 
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White
            };
            entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Quantity");

            grid.Children.Add(typeLabel,0,0);
            grid.Children.Add(entry,1,0);
            grid.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;


            return new ViewCell { View = grid };
        });

        listView.ItemTemplate = productDataTemplate;
        listView.ItemsSource = products;
         listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
            DisplayAlert("item tapped", e.SelectedItem.ToString(), "ok");
        };


        wrapLayout.Children.Add(listView);
```

Comment: Great! Just one thing; I don't see anything in your question about what _you_ have tried. Did you try anything yet to achieve this? If so, what? And where have you failed? StackOverflow is not a service that will code for you. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Xamarin.forms by default supports Tap, Pinch & Pan gesture. So to do long press you need to handle with the CustomRenderer for each supported platforms or you can make use of [XForms lab](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) which by default supports most of the gestures which includes Long Press. Hope that helps!